# Latest version of Ajax Control toolkit loading 150 .axd files

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have installed the latest version of Ajax Control Toolkit, it is loading 150 ScriptResource.axd files approx. which is taking long time to load which in turn is making my website very slow, please suggest how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of Ajax Control toolkit is loading all the scripts by default, you have to code manually so that you can load only the required scripts for the used controls on the page. For Achieving this functionality, you have to create AjaxControlToolkit.config to define the bundles which in turn can be used by the individual pages. Please follow the below links it explains all the functionality that is required by you:
http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2013/07/25/july-2013-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit
https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SampleWebSites/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxControlToolkit.config